# How to git cat-file on a remote without having to clone first?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm trying to use git to read a file content on a remote without having to first clone the repository (kind of like `git cat-file` but from the remote).

For more context on the final goal. There's many repos out there exposing bash scripts we can curl and run locally. For example

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL raw.github.com/sboudrias/dotfiles/master/bin/dotfiles)"
```

This works for open source repo on Github since they're public. But this wouldn't work for either private repos or self-hosted gitlab instances.

Since git SSH authentication is already setup, I'm hoping to find a way to get the content of a file on a remote to run it before the user downloaded a whole clone.

Comment: You cannot do it with GIt — Git is for local operations. You shouldn't do it accessing raw data. You should use API. Both GitHub and GitLab have APIs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  git commands work within the context of a repository; they don't accept repositories as arguments.  You have to have a local copy of the repository, and operate the `git cat-file` within that repository to get the file contents with that tool.

Comment: But this is not 100% true right, `git archive` for example works on remotes and take the remote as an argument. So yeah cat-file is only local, but git itself has some utilities to work with remotes directly.